# Saving a new item with a versioned attribute using DynamoDBMapper

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following DynamoDB item in Scala

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = Table)
class DynamoItem {
  private var indexId: String = _
  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = IndexIdAttribute)
  def getIndexId: String = {
    indexId
  }
  def setIndexId(id: String): Unit = {
    indexId = id
  }

  private var version: Long = _
  @DynamoDBVersionAttribute(attributeName = VersionAttribute)
  def getVersion: Long = {
    version
  }
  def setVersion(version: Long): Unit = {
    this.version = version
  }
}
```

I am trying to save a new DynamoItem in the table as follows

```
val item = new DynamoItem
item.setIndexId(id = 1L)
// Not setting any version as DynamoDBMapper is supposed to automatically
// set it to 1 for new objects
val dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBClient)
val dynamoDBMapperConfig = (new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder).
    withConsistentReads(ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT).
    withSaveBehavior(SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES).
    build()

dynamoDBMapper.save(item(), dynamoDBMapperConfig)
```

However, I end up getting a `ConditionalCheckFailedException` on the save call. 
Things I have already done/verified:

1. I verified that the item does not already exist in the table (it's null).
2. I used `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` as the SaveBehavior so that null attributes are not removed. For what it's worth, using `UPDATE` as the SaveBehavior also gives the same exception.
3. I have also tried setting the version of the new object as 0L and 1L. Same exception again.

So, the question is how do I save a new object with a versioned attribute using DynamoDBMapper? I need this because I am using optimistic locking and am hoping to get putIfAbsent semantics through this (if the item is already present, fail with a `ConditionFailedCheckException`, otherwise succeed by creating a new item with version 1).

Comment: Have you tried with Java class for the above model rather than scala?

Answer (score 3):

Scala's Long is not compatible with DynamoDBVersionAttribute for initial saves because it is not nullable. When you initialize Long as _ it uses the default value, 0L. If you instead use java.lang.Long, you can initialize it as null which will make the save work without conditional checks failing.